# NodeMCU 0.9.6-dev on ESP 8266 (devkit v2): while dofile() script is not connecting to TCP-server

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

As mentioned I wrote a script that is connecting to a weather API and printing out the result.

Everything works fine when I run it line by line through the interpreter (ESPlorer "Send to ESP- and run "line by line""), but when I execute it via `dofile()` it cannot connect to the site and fails.

I am confused and hope some of you would find the mistake I am ignoring.

**Here is the code:**

```
data= ""
s= net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
s:on("receive", function(so, da) data= da end)
s:connect(80, "api.openweathermap.org")
s:send("GET /data/2.5/weather?q=berlin,de&appid=9a3719c191ce0e1e70673f892013647e&units=metric HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.api.openweathermap.org\r\n\r\n")
for x in string.gmatch(data, "([^\n]+)") do
    if string.find(x, '"coord"') ~= nil then
        for k,v in pairs(cjson.decode(x)) do
            if k == "main" or k == "weather" then 
            print("++++++"..k.."++++++")
            if type(v) == "table" then
                for kz, vz in pairs(v) do
                    if kz == 1 or kz == 2 then
                        for kd,vd in pairs(vz) do
                            print(kd,vd)
                        end 
                    else print(kz,vz) end
                    end end end
end end end
s:close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use those old 0.9.x pre-built binaries as they're outdated, no longer supported and contain lots of bugs.

[Build your own NodeMCU firmware](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/build/) ideally from the `dev` branch (Espressif SDK 1.5.1).

Then you need to get accustomed to the asynchronous event-driven nature of the NodeMCU firmware. It was a bug in the old SDKs that `net.socket:send()` was ever blocking (i.e. non-asynchronous).

Hence, you need to process the incoming data in the `s:on('receive')` callback and you need to wait with sending the request in `s:on('connection')`. Here's the template:

```
conn = net.createConnection()
conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload)
    -- processing data
end)
conn:on("connection", function(conn, payload)
    -- conn:send
end)
conn:connect(80, "api.openweathermap.org")
```

Have a look at the API docs at https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/net/.

Side note: there's an HTTP (client) module in the `dev` branch that simplifies access to remote resources over HTTP.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.

Comment: Good to know. If this solves your problem please accept and/upvote the answer so that StackOverflow can mark this case as closed.